# Display the value of my label create from *ngFor Angular

Tags: angular, binding

I almost finish this little project but it miss one thing and i don't find a solution about it.

I have this form with input and label and when i select an input i want that the value displays on the other view in the tag `<p>`.

So if i pick 1 and i submit i want the text says "**you selected 1 on 5**"

I tried différent solution like access to the DOM and try to stock the value of my label but they are create with `*ngFor` so it isn't work.

If someone had an idea it will be cool !

My repo : https://github.com/qalimero/rating-app

The HTML :

```html
    <main role="main">
      <div *ngIf="!display; then displayRate else displayResult"></div>
      <ng-template #displayRate>
        <div class="header-rating" role="heading">
          <fa-icon [icon]="faStar"></fa-icon>
          <h1>How did we do ?</h1>
        </div>
        <p class="text-body">
          Please let us know how we did with your support request. All feedback is appreciated 
          to help us improve our offering!
        </p>
        <form>
          <ul class="radio-wrapper">
            <li *ngFor='let radio of radios; let idx = index' [ngClass]="['radio']">
              <input (focus)="onFocus()" (change)="isChecked = true" class="visually-hidden"  
               id="rate_{{ idx }}" name="rate" type="radio">
              <label #label [ngClass]="['custom-checkbox']"
                     for="rate_{{ idx }}">{{ idx }}</label>
            </li>
          </ul>
          <button (click)="submitResult()" [disabled]="!focus"  type="button">SUBMIT</button>
        </form>
      </ng-template>
      <ng-template #displayResult>
        <div class="header-result">
          <img src="../../assets/images/illustration-thank-you.svg" alt="">
          <p class="resume-result">You selected on 5 </p>
          <h2>Thank you!</h2>
          <p>We appreciate you taking the time to give a rating. If you ever need more support, 
             don’t hesitate to get in
            touch!
          </p>
        </div>
      </ng-template>
    </main>
```

TS :

```js
    import {Component} from '@angular/core';
    import {faStar} from "@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons";
    import {formatNumber} from "@angular/common";
    
    @Component({
      selector: 'app-rating-component',
      templateUrl: './rating.component.html',
      styleUrls: ['./rating.component.scss']
    })
    export class RatingComponent {
      display = false;
      faStar = faStar;
      radios = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];
      isChecked = false;
      focus = false;
    
      constructor() {
      }
    
      submitResult() {
        this.display = !this.display;
      }
      onFocus() {
        this.focus = true;
      }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can attach a value to each radio with `[value]`. Then access that value through the HTML element on change.

```html
<li *ngFor="let radio of radios">
  <input
    type="radio"
    name="rate"
    [value]="radio"
    (change)="onChange($event.target)"
  />
  <label>{{ radio }}</label>
</li>

<p *ngIf="selected" class="resume-result">You selected {{ selected }} on 5</p>
```

```js
  radios = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];
  selected = '';

  onChange(target: EventTarget) {
    const radio = target as HTMLInputElement;
    this.selected = radio.value;
  }
```

Stackblitz: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-ywbkbg?file=src/app/app.component.ts